# compare three textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem. I have to compare one textbox with two other textboxes and if values match then they should show an error message.

I have tried two compare validators but only one compare validator works at a time, so get the first value only see my code.

```html
<asp:CompareValidator ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" 
     ID="CompareValidator2" controltovalidate="txtsponsorfatherhusbandname" 
     controltocompare="txtfatherhusbandname" operator="NotEqual" type="String" 
     errormessage="Sponsor and applicant father name cannot be same" SetFocusOnError="true">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" 
     ID="cmpfather" controltovalidate="txtsponsorname" 
     controltocompare="txtfatherhusbandname" operator="NotEqual" type="String" 
     errormessage="Sponsor and applicant father name cannot be same" SetFocusOnError="true">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

I had used coding it from code file but problem is that it has to refresh the page so if there is any help it will appreciated.
[see the picture i want to check if applicant name is not equal to either Sponsor name and sponsor father husband name and if they are equal then they show a message and focus is on applicant name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IueV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomValidator` for that. You can write your own logic inside the `ClientValidationFunction`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<br />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ClientValidationFunction="checkAll3Boxes" ErrorMessage="All three are the same"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll3Boxes(sender, element) {
        var tb1 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
        var tb2 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;
        var tb3 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>').value;

        if (tb1 != "" && tb1 == tb2 && tb1 == tb3) {
            element.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            element.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this script is not showing any message in front of textbox after statement id invalid

Comment: i had tried 
sender.innerHTML = "YOUR HTML WITH ANYTHING COME HERE";
document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerHTML = 'your tip has been submitted!';  but the value of label is also not changing

Comment: The `ErrorMessage` of the CustomValidator is shown.

Comment: Yes there is. If not you have javascript errors. Check the browser console. And i've updated to a complete example. Copy this to a blank page and you'll see that it works.

Comment: working in blank page but on button click but not working on textbox changes text i had tried autopostback="true" but not working